# PHP | Как найти похожое словосочетание в массиве

Tags: php, алгоритм, search

Как можно реализовать нечто похожее на гугловское «Возможно, вы имели в виду: ...»

Я прочел https://habr.com/ru/post/115394/, но оно касается только для поиска по одному слову.

У меня есть массави с словосочетаний, по которым нужно искать похожее.

Как это можно реализовать или прочесть об этом?